# Unable to load multiple rows dynamically on html page from json response

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am developing an application in which I want to display rows dynamically from database to html page using JavaScript.The response received is in form of json. Here is my function-->

```
function residence() {
    var id = localStorage.getItem("uid");
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/api/residence_api/residenceCheck",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            uid: id
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var response = eval(data);
            if (response.error == "1") {
                $("#errorMsg").html("<div  class=\"message error\">" + response.response + ".</div>");
            } else {
                window.location = "http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/residence";
                var rows = '';
                for (var i = 0; i < response.response.length; i++) {
                    rows += '<tr><td class="country">' + response.response[i].country + '</td><td                 class="state">' + response.response[i].state + '</td><td     class="city">' + response.response[i].city + '</td></tr>';
                }
                document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].innerHTML += rows;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

When I click on the button(residence) residence function gets called ,while loading page I can see the generated results on the html page for a few seconds and again the page becomes blank with no output. Why so?
Please help......
Thanks in advance..!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its success must be so:

```
success: function (data) {
        var response = eval(data);
        if (response.error == "1") {
            $("#errorMsg").html("<div  class=\"message error\">" + response.response + ".</div>");
        } else {
            var rows = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < response.response.length; i++) {
                rows += '<tr><td class="country">' + response.response[i].country + '</td><td                 class="state">' + response.response[i].state + '</td><td     class="city">' + response.response[i].city + '</td></tr>';
            }
            document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].innerHTML += rows;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think window.location = "http://localhost/codeigniter/index.php/residence"; Is important why have you removed it?....Any specific reason?

Comment: you want to redirect to this page? if it instead of you making an ajax call, submit your page to the values ​​they want to lead and bring the page already mounted